# how to use of select with multi condition in zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-select

i want to select rows with multi condition in zend framework how can i implement that/

1-example "select id,firstname,lastname,city from person where firstname=alex **and** city=xx ";
2-example "select id,firstname,lastname,city from person where firstname=alex **or** city=xx ";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$firstname = 'alex';
$city = 'xx';

// AND query
$select = $adapter->select()
    ->from('person', array('id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'city')
    ->where('firstname = ?', $firstname)
    ->where('city ?', $city);


// OR query
$select = $adapter->select()
    ->from('person', array('id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'city')
    ->where('firstname = ?', $firstname)
    ->orWhere('city = ?', $city);
```

Take a look at the [`Zend_Db_Select`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html) manual to see more examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the examples in [Zend.DB manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html)

```
  // Build this query:
  //   SELECT product_id, product_name, price
  //   FROM "products"
  //   WHERE (price < 100.00 OR price > 500.00)
  //     AND (product_name = 'Apple')

  $minimumPrice = 100;
  $maximumPrice = 500;
  $prod = 'Apple';

  $select = $db->select()
               ->from('products',
                      array('product_id', 'product_name', 'price'))
               ->where("price < $minimumPrice OR price > $maximumPrice")
               ->where('product_name = ?', $prod);
```

Comment: In this part "price < $minimumPrice OR price > $maximumPrice" the variables are not sanitized. This can lead to SQL injections.

Comment: Sorry for -1. Didn´t know the example came from manual. It´s wrong, but It´s not your fault. If you edit your question I can undo the vote.

Comment: On one hand you are correct, but on the other it's completely safe as both the variables are defined 3 lines before and are integers. I agree though that if someone copies over only the select it may be problem. For the sake of explaining how to construct query it's more clear.